# Avoid re-rendering child component NgRx - Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, ngrx

I'm looking for a way to resolve a case where 1 property of my model is updated from firestore, but all the detail (child) component is being re-rendered.

For example my model has author, title, image, & **likesCount**. When NumberOfLikes is updated Firestore sends a Modified action, with a Payload that goes through my ItemReducer in ngrx:

```
   case actions.MODIFIED:
        return itemAdapter.updateOne({
            id: action.payload.url,
            changes: action.payload
        }, state);
```

This updates only one object in my array of Items, however when the child component gets updated for that specific item, it re-renders all 4 properties instead of just **likesCount** only, causing an annoying flashing.

I don't think ChangeDetectionStrategy, that I implemented in both the parent and child components, is helping here. Wonder if there is a way to for the child component to update only **likesCount** property.

As I understand ngrx is passing a new reference and the Async pipe I have also plays a role to re-render the child component.

Thanks for taking the time. Will appreciate any advice.

Container Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from './../../../models/item';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-specials',
    styleUrls: ['specials-list.component.scss'],
    template: `
<div *ngIf="items$ | async; let items; else noItems">
  <app-item-detail
    *ngFor="let item of items"
    [detail]="item">
  </app-item-detail>
</div>`,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.items$ = this.store.select(fromItem.selectAll);
}
...
```

Child Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
...
@Input()
detail: Item;
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally just pulled out `likesCount` into a service. Should have designed it this way from the beginning.